# Could Baron software be called in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, cplex

I usually do programming with Python and call Cplex to solve the optimization models. Now, I have a nonlinear model and I do not want to linearize that. So I cannot use CPLEX to solve it (I think the model is concave as well). I need to call Baron to solve this model and transfer the results in another model that can be solved by Cplex. I already used Barron with Matlab interface. But I could not find any information regarding how to call Baron in Python. I am wondering if you have some information to share with me.

I really appreciate that.

Comment: Python can call a lot of things. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: Does this help?  http://www.pyomo.org

Comment: @ tadman, I would like to install  Barons 16.5.11. however I found only [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/baron/0.6.2#downloads]. My first question is how to install baron in python. From the above link I installed Baron 0.6.2 by:[pip install " C:\Users\my name\Downloads\baron-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl"] . That is not the right version. Then I do not know how can I do coding compatible with Barron in Python.

Comment: @cdarke, I am not familiar with Pyomo, but it seems it works with Barron.

Comment: You can also try Couenne. Both Baron and Couenne work with Pyomo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit too late. But one work around is installing the python package [matlab engine](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html): 
this allows you to call any matlab function from python. [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html) it is described how it works.